# Scrolling a ListView inside a GestureDetector

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to detect when a `ListView` is scrolled so that I can dismiss the keyboard at that time.

Currently, I have my `ListView` wrapped in a `GestureDetector`. The `onVerticalDragStart` of the gesture detector is set to dismiss the keyboard. However, when I intercept the event like this, it is preventing the drag event from bubbling downward to the `ListView` so I can't actually scroll the view anymore.

I tried setting `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` on the `GestureDetector` but for some reason this didn't do what I wanted. How can I achieve this behavior without subclassing `ListView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the `ListView` in a `GestureDetector`, why don't you just add a listener (via the method `addListener`) to a `ScrollController` (assuming you already aren't using one) that calls a `VoidCallback` every time the state changes?

Comment: It turned out that since my `ListView` had unbounded height, the `ScrollController` callback didn't fire. Fixed that and was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the `ListView` in a [`NotificationListener`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) instead of a `GestureDetector`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to capture scroll events within the ListView. It's only firing when buttons within the ListView are pressed.